# loop on inserting data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i want to insert data through loop in mysql table but it insert only a time when loop execute where i want to insert 500 Times the same data into my table below are the codes thanks in advance

```
enter code here



<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","khan","first");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

for($i=1;$i<500;$i++)
{
 $sql="INSERT INTO bio(name, fathername , address) VALUES('khan','khan','khan')";  
 echo "Number " . $i . "<br>";
}

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest doing a bulk insert instead of 500 separate queries.

Comment: I really dont think this question earns downvotes. He has a problem he cannot figure out so we should help him. That's why there's stackoverflow. Not just for questions no-one knows the answer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you insert only after the loop

Try this:

```
for($i=1;$i<500;$i++)
{
 $sql="INSERT INTO bio(name, fathername , address) VALUES('khan','khan','khan')";  
 echo "Number " . $i . "<br>";

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
}
```

As you can see, now the `mysqli_query` is inside the loop and so it will execute 500 times and not just one (notice the `{ }` positioning.

Also try not to use `die();`
Use proper error handling instead of this.

for instance:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 500; $i++) {
//INSERT AND STUFF
if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
echo "Something went wrong. Try again.";
break;
}
}
```

of course you might want to return what has gone wrong. So the actual error that happened in your SQL.

[Look at the Mysqli documentation for this.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

If you put this in a function, you dont need to use `break;`. Instead you can use the `return "something";` statement to return the error and quit the for-loop.

Now you will end up with:

```
function insertFunction() {
   for(.....
       //DO INSERT
       if(!mysqli_query(...
            return "Errormessage: "+ $mysqli->error;

}
```

in addition you might want to look at prepared statements for your insert and how to make sure you only do 1 insert with 500 records instead of querying the database 500 times.

[This might get you started on prepared statements](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-mysqli/)

Answer (score 0):

Include `mysqli_query` inside of `for` scope

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","khan","first"); 
// Check connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
} 

for($i=1;$i<500;$i++) { 
    $mysqli_query ="INSERT INTO bio(name, fathername , address) VALUES('khan','khan','khan')";
    echo "Number " . $i . "<br>"; 
    // <<-- you always leave a closing bracket here 
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { 
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); 
    } 
} 
mysqli_close($con);
```

Now you can do that on db side without any loops with the query

```
INSERT INTO bio(name, fathername , address)
SELECT 'khan','khan','khan'
  FROM
(
select a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 + 1 n
from (select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) a
      , (select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) b
      , (select 0 as N union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) c
) t
WHERE t.n < 501
```

See more on populating a table with fake data https://stackoverflow.com/a/17139749/1920232

Comment: thanks bro , u mean like this but it do the same i dont know why                                        
 $mysqli_query ="INSERT INTO bio(name, fathername , address) VALUES('khan','khan','khan')";

Comment: @ismailkhan Please copy code exactly. In what you've just posted in comments again `mysqli_query` is out of loop. You've left extra curly bracket after `echo`. Remove it.

Comment: <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","khan","first");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

for($i=1;$i<500;$i++)
{
 $mysqli_query ="INSERT INTO bio(name, fathername , address) VALUES('khan','khan','khan')";  
 echo "Number " . $i . "<br>";
}


 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You did it again. Pay attention to opening and closing brackets. See updated answer.